# Selenium | Not able to click on button, exception as org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:Origin element is not displayed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

On trying to hit login button, below exception is thrown.
I used java script executor as well as action class button but none of these works.

```
public void LoginApplication(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    
    System.out.println(LoginPageLocators.userEmail);
    waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), LoginPageLocators.userEmail);
    LoginPageLocators.userEmail.sendKeys(username);
    waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), LoginPageLocators.userLogin);
    LoginPageLocators.userLogin.click();
    waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), LoginPageLocators.enterPass);
    //LoginPageLocators.enterPass.sendKeys(password);
    actionEnterText(driver, LoginPageLocators.enterPass, 5, password);
    waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), LoginPageLocators.loginApp);
    jsClick(driver, LoginPageLocators.loginApp); // Error
}
```

Locator :   @FindBy(css="input#okta-signin-submit")
public static WebElement loginApp;

> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
> Origin element is not displayed Build info: version: '4.8.1',
> revision: '8ebccac989' System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
> 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19' Driver info:
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Command:
> [0bedc7c0-68f4-49d8-a6c4-ffc811d06322, actions
> {actions=[org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence@8a62297]}]
> Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox,
> browserVersion: 112.0, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID:
> 20230406114409, moz:debuggerAddress: 127.0.0.1:45356,
> moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.33.0, moz:headless: false,
> moz:platformVersion: 10.0, moz:processID: 21252, moz:profile:
> C:\Users\shipawar\AppData\L..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000,
> moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true,
> moz:windowless: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName:
> WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://127.0.0.1:45356/devtoo...,
> se:cdpVersion: 85.0, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability:
> false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000},
> unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify} Session ID:
> 0bedc7c0-68f4-49d8-a6c4-ffc811d06322  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:611)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:567)
> at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:536)
> at POM.SeleniumUtlities.actionEnterText(SeleniumUtlities.java:65)   at
> POM.WebElementsQuoting.LoginApplication(WebElementsQuoting.java:38)
> at
> stepDefinition.MyStepDefinitions.user_login_into_application_with_username_and_password(MyStepDefinitions.java:39)
> at ✽.user login into application with "maria.roark@aos5.com" and
> "Cisco@2423"(file:///C:/Users/shipawar/eclipse-workspace/Automation/src/test/java/features/Login.feature:5)